# How to use barssince function since specific time

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way I can use the barssince function to return the number of bars since a specific time occurring each day?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
[image]

Code:

```
//@version=4
study("Time test")
specificTime = hour == 14 and minute == 0
plot(barssince(specificTime))
```